# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Mac OS Monterey

Tags: c++, linux, macos, gcc

Кроссплатформенная программа которая идеально работала на всех устройствах, перестала компилироваться на MacOs Monterey. ( до этого работал на Mojave ). Я предположил что дело в command line tools, и попытался сделать даунгрейд, но ось не разрешила. Какие варианты решения проблемы? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала лучше текст показывать как текст. То, как ужасно выглядят шрифты на маке и так все знают.

Во вторых, у Вас код прекрасно компилируется. Он не линкуется.

В третьих, у Вас не gcc, а clang (но это мелочи).

А вот [здесь на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207051/fopenunix2003-referenced-from-openssl-problem) пишут, что это известная проблема и предлагают как минимум два варианта решения.